# Syntax error in UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql

i have "(Syntax error in UPDATE statement)" when I updating the record in access database by c#

```
string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=E:\C#\شغل\Host-CO\Host-CO\bin\Debug\hostco.accdb";
        string Query = "update host set رقم المريضه='" + رقم_المريضهTextBox.Text + "',المبلغ المسترد='" + المبلغ_المستردTextBox.Text + "',المبلغ='" + المبلغTextBox.Text + "',التاريخ='" + التاريخDateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString() + "'where الأسم='" + textBox1.Text + "';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Do you honestly think we can read that?

Comment: so print out the value of the Query string and examine that.

Comment: Is this good to read?

Comment: Does your provider not support parameters? That is **ripe** for SQL injection, which is : a Very Bad Thing. It would also make it much easier to get the query right...

Comment: Can You help me to made it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say where exactly the error is, especially with all those non-ASCII characters. As OldProgrammer said, one possibility to debug this is to put a breakpoint below the initialization of the variable and examine the result of the concatenation - this result could be tested in your DB environment and maybe you get more precise error messages.

But as Marc Gravell said, everything would be much better with parameters. Your statement could be written as follows (I do not use your exact query as I have some difficulties editing text with different flows of direction in my environment):

```
string Query = "update host set [field1] = ?, [field2] = ?";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("field1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = field1TextBox.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("field2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = field2TextBox.Text;

try {
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Updated");
    con.Close();
}
```

I added "[...]" around the field names because non-ACSII characters in field names *may* cause troubles if they are not escaped. For more details see also:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx